# What is the suggested way to install multiple Python interpreters?

Tags: python, ubuntu, installation

With Ubuntu, only certain Python versions are available from the repositories. They're easy to get, but with the rest, it's not so obvious. While I can certainly build them from source, I'm thinking there must be tools to automate the process but I can't find them.

Comment: virtualenv ... that is all

Comment: my understanding of `virtualenv` is that it creates separate Python environments, but it does not act as a tool to install Python interpreters.

Comment: I'm not aware of any such tool for Ubuntu. Probably building from source is best option if you want to work with different versions of python that are normally available in Ubuntu.

Comment: are you aware of such a tool for any OS?

Comment: you install python inside the virtual env ... it comes with one version but easy to change

Comment: still, that doesn't cover the suggested way of how to install the interpreters themselves.

Comment: I figured out what you were saying ... hence the deleted comment ... that said this ppa looks good https://launchpad.net/~fkrull/+archive/ubuntu/deadsnakes , and see this answer to set it up http://askubuntu.com/a/446278/342078

Comment: in windows I download executable installers typically ... but yeah I guess so ... what were you hoping for exactly? apt-get install is pretty easy ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows and OS X users can simply use executable installers available on the Python website. This is not true with the other OS options. If your Linux distribution's repositories do not contain all the versions you want, building from source is the recommended way, at least as far as the website is concerned.

Automating this process is possible. [`pythonbrew`](https://github.com/utahta/pythonbrew) is a now-deprecated installation manager that recommends shell script-based [`pyenv`](https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv) instead. With this, installing a new version is as simple as

```
pyenv install <version number, e.g. 2.7.3>
```

Another alternative is the more Python-based (read: cross platform) [`pythonz`](https://github.com/saghul/pythonz), a fork of the original `pythonbrew`. It is just as easy:

```
pythonz install <version number, e.g. 2.7.3>
```

Answer (score 1):

One way of installing multiple versions of Python in Ubuntu is to use Felix Krull's [deadsnakes ppa](https://launchpad.net/~fkrull/+archive/ubuntu/deadsnakes), which includes all the *major* releases from 2.3 on (not point releases) if they are not already in the Ubuntu repositories. It only supports currently supported Ubuntu versions. There is no guarantee of updates, but it does make getting different versions easy.

To install the necessary repositories:

```bash
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:fkrull/deadsnakes
$ sudo apt-get update
```

If you want to install 2.7, it's as easy as:

```bash
$ sudo apt-get install python2.7
```

Note this only works for Ubuntu, not e.g. Debian.

Comment: Note I didn't see all the comments above and cannot comment directly. Other versions of Linux support more versions of Python in their repositories, however there is also PythonBrew, see this article http://www.ken-far.com/2013/03/installing-python-with-pythonbrew.html?m=1

Comment: dependency issues with this. probably due to other packages i have installed and their dependence on python, but still, not a great solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
$ sudo apt-get update
```

To install Python2.7, just enter:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python2.7
```